# How to have xRDP acknowledge current user's locale?

Tags: mate, language-support, locale, xrdp

My problem is that xRDP does not seem to recognize the `~/.pam_environment` file of the user, who is being logged in.

What I did:

- I have set up a fresh Ubuntu Server 18.04.02 LTS
- I installed MATE as the desktop environment
- I installed xRDP
- I have created 2 more users

What I can do:

- I can successfully login from Windows (10) into a session for every user
- I can start mate locally just fine and login with every user into their own sessions

I installed German as an additional language in `Menu > Control Center > Language Support` and reordered German (`Deutschland (Deutsch)`) to be above `English` (fallback I assume).

Now when I log in with user1 **locally**, I see the MATE desktop environment in English, and when I login with user2, I see it in German.

However: when I log in via a remote RDP-session (via Xorg) from my Windows computer using the corresponding credentials, the MATE desktop environment stays English no matter what user logs in.

I suspect that xRDP is drawing its information about the locale to use from `/etc/default/locale`, which has the following content:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

According to this the language is expected to stay English.

**Am I missing something?**

**Edit:** adjustments in `~/.profile` I thought were necessary, actually are not. It works regardless, because **locally** `~/.pam_environment` is used. Via xRDP for whatever reason it seems not to be recognized.

**Edit 2:**
Output from `locale` when `user2` is logged in **locally**:

```
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="de_DE:en"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Output from `locale` when `user2` is logged in **remotely**:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What does the `locale` command output when you are logged in remotely?

Comment: It outputs the contents of `etc/default/locale`. I can copy & paste it as soon as I am home.

Comment: Please do. I'd like to see the exact output.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I added the outputs for user2 (local and remote).

Comment: The first (local) is not a complete `locale` output. But I was most interested in seeing if there was something odd in the remote one. Seems not. Unfortunately I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: Although not exactly what you want, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311346/968501) is related.